# Raspberry PI in C, assembler inline for reading GPIO (or other memory address)

Tags: c, assembly, arm, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to do assembler inline in my C code but for some reason i just crush my program.
I don't know assembler but with some tutorials and google i manage to write the code:

```
inside a c function...
...
int y=0;
asm volatile(
        "ldr r1,=0x20200000 \n"

        "ldr r0,[r1]\n"         //This is the line which crashes
                                //If i remove it the program runs 
                                //(but without doing the job)
        "mov %[result],r0\n"
        ".LTORG"
        :[result]"=r"(y)        /* output list*/
        :                       /* input list*/
        :"memory"               /* clobber register list */
        );
printf("The Address value is:%x", y);
back to the c function
...
```

Can someone help me with this one.
I just need to read memory and give it to C.

I tried with different addresses but it always crashes.
(compiling everything with gcc on Raspberry Pi )

Comment: Without knowing ARM assembler, don't you mean either `ldr r1,=0x20200000` or `ldr r0,[r0]`? Right now you use register `r1` without setting it to anything.

Comment: Why would you need inline assembly for this? Couldn't you just write `y = *(volatile int*)0x20200000;` ?

Comment: Are you doing this from user space from Linux?  If so, then that's likely your problem.  Linux doesn't allow direct access to peripherals from user space, you have to go through a driver of some sort, or you need to write yourself a kernel driver.  This [link](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/index.html) might be useful.  It allows access to certain GPIO from user space on the Raspberry Pi via a C library.

Comment: Well this wont answer your question but, There is a lib known as wiringpi. https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/ very simple to use and gives you pretty much all you want, when working with the gpio on the RPI